# Angular dentro de pagina aspx

Tags: angular, angular5

Hice una aplicación en Angular 5 y ésta debe ser cargada en una página aspx; intenté utilizando un iframe pero no me carga, así que mi segunda opción fue utilizar jQuery y cargar la página en un div:

este es mi código

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $("#angular").load('https://localhost:4200');
});
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://localhost:4200"></iframe>
    </div>
        <div id="angular"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

En la consola aparece este error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

"Googleando" tu pregunta encontré una guía completa del procedimiento para [usar una aplicación Angular 4 en un proyecto ASP.NET 4.x](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015) directamente en la documentación de Angular. Recuerda tener en cuenta las  [diferencias entre las versiones 4 y 5 de Angular](https://victorroblesweb.es/2017/11/02/actualizar-proyecto-angular-4-a-angular-5/)